# Is there a api/ way to get available disk size in chrome book programatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am storing files(videos/images) in local folder in chrome book, I want to store the files until it reaches certain disk space and delete the files. Is there a way to get disk space programatically in chrome OS?

I checked https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_storage but these are for external storage devices.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [chrome.system.storage.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_storage) could help you, please be aware `StorageUnitInfo.type` has the following enums, while `fixed` is what you want.

> - fixed
>
>   The storage has fixed media, e.g. hard disk or SSD.
> - removable
>
>   The storage is removable, e.g. USB flash drive.
> - unknown
>
>   The storage type is unknown.

Comment: I tried with storage api but I was only able to get the thumb drive information but not the built in disk space on chrome OS. I was able to get  built in disk space in Windows.

Comment: I was looking into the capability of retrieving the fixed media's capacity. What I've found is the same as Amanda - the total disk space is available through the API for Chrome on **Windows** and **Linux** (have not tried Mac but I suspect it is also available).

On Chrome OS though, that information is not available through nor any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) API
1. You must declare the `unlimitedStorage` permission in your manifest
2. You can query your storage usage and availability via `queryUsageAndQuota`

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#queryUsageAndQuota

For example (copied directly from the link):

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    }, 
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

From what I understand, since you declared `unlimitedStorage`, the call returns the total available space on the device.